# Lodash create a collection from a collection

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following data structure;

```
var data = [{
    "username": "admin",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:44:14"
}, {
    "username": "admin",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:00"
}, {
    "username": "joebloggs",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:00"
}, {
    "username": "joebloggs",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:44:14"
}];
```

Using the lodash library, I would like to create the following data structure;

```
var newData = [{
    "username": "admin",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:00"
}, {
    "username": "joebloggs",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:00"
}];
```

As you can see, I need to remove the duplicate names and store only the most recent date. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [orderBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy) to order the collection by the `update` date value in descending order and then use [uniqBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy) to remove duplicate values.

```js
var data = [{
    "username": "admin",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:44:14"
}, {
    "username": "admin",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:00"
}, {
    "username": "joebloggs",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:00"
}, {
    "username": "joebloggs",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:44:14"
}];

var result = _(data)
  .orderBy(v => new Date(v.update), 'desc')
  .uniqBy('username')
  .value();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the `update` date values are not compliant with [IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and [version of ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) date formats, check [Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as a reference. Therefore the solution above does not apply properly with the **most recent date** criteria.

You have two options to solve this problem:

1. Change the way you format the `update` date values from the source (backend or whichever resource you got it from). This way the solution above still applies.
2. Convert the date format on run time. The solution for this is shown below:

```js
var data = [{
    "username": "admin",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:44:14"
}, {
    "username": "admin",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:00"
}, {
    "username": "joebloggs",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:00"
}, {
    "username": "joebloggs",
    "update": "19/07/2015 17:44:14"
}];

var result = _(data)
  .orderBy(v => {
    var ds = v.update.split(' ');
    ds[0] = ds[0].split('/').reverse().join('/');
    return new Date(ds.join(' '));
  }, 'desc')
  .uniqBy('username')
  .value();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can it be that easy? I have been racking my brains all day to get my head around this. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, it's an old system which I am trying to generate some reports from. It's not something we will want to fix, however our new solution does solve this. Thank you for putting the update here, this will be a useful reference for me in the future. Do you know of a way that I could use momentjs to get some nice formatting on the `update`?

Comment: @KarlBateman Please don't ask two questions in one post. A separate question makes it more useful to others

Comment: This is relevant to the already asked question, would that not create a duplicate of this?

Comment: @KarlBateman, to use momentjs, you need to have your dates in a proper format indicated on the answer. Converting the formats on runtime may help you.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try.